# Enable browser caching for static resources with Spring MVC,Tomcat application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, caching, browser-cache

I am using `Tomcat-7, Spring-4, Hibernate-4` in my application. I have tried two approaches to make `caching` work but they don't seem to be working when I checked with `gtmetrix`.

## Approach-1 using `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
  ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
```

## Approach-2 using Spring MVC xml Config `mvc:interceptors` :

```
<mvc:interceptors>
   <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/resources/*"/>
        <bean id="webContentInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
          <property name="cacheSeconds" value="31556926"/>
          <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
          <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
          <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
 </mvc:interceptors>
```

What are the other approaches that I can use with `Tomcat, Spring-MVC` to make `browser caching` work ?
 Please share your experience.

Comment: However I have accepted Burak's answer, but I am still interested in knowing more approaches for `caching of static resources `.

Answer (score 2):

The other approach is this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/public-resources/" 
       cache-period="31556926"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Burak. It worked.   By the way how can I to set different cache-period for different resources like for css cache-period will be 1 month , for js it would by 1 year. any idea ?